# OnBeforeNavigate2 is getting fired in case of re-direct for IE10 but not for IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I am testing url `www.google.com` using selenium.I have BHO written which has handlers for different events.In case of IE10, OnBeforeNavigate2 event handler gets fired even for internal redirects involved. But, for IE11 OnBeforeNavigate2 is not getting fired for redirects.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Try to provide detailed information about your issue like which kind of project you are developing? which developing language you are using? If there are any steps than try to provide steps and sample code to reproduce the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Can you try to provide your sample BHO which can produce the issue? We can try to test it with IE 11 to check for the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Sharing entire code is not possible. We are using BeforeNavigate2 Event API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa768326(v%3Dvs.85)) to detect before navigate in IE. We have not written any code specific to any version of IE. It's just when this event occurs, respective handler present in our code will be called. But, like I said behaviour is different for IE11 and IE10. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Not sure, which OS and which specific update you are using for making this test with IE 11 browser. I try to find some information on this issue and I found that there was some bug. Information about that update is not available currently. but you can refer this link for a work around to check whether it helps to solve the issue or not. Ref: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/20b16462-63bd-4df4-8f2f-900307252ede and https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/343487/BeforeNavigate2-in-an-IE-estension and https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/441/how-can-i-catch-the-beforenavigate2-event

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thanks for the response. Are you saying that OnBeforeNavigate2 should be fired in case of a page redirect by default for IE11? We don't have to set any flag for this feature to work?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT OnBeforeNavigate2 is getting called even for IE11 but not for the redirected case. Suppose url1 redirects to url2. In case of IE11, onBeforeNavigate2 is called just once for url1 but not for the redirect case to url2. However, in case of IE10, there will be two onBeforeNavigate events fired. I want to know why this difference in behaviour and also if there is a way to turn on/off this functionality to call onBeforeNavigate2 event in case of redirect.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT The OS I am using is Windows 2012 R2.

Comment: I think this difference can be caused by the different settings for security and IE options. Try to check the settings for both the browsers and try to make it similar may help to make it work for IE 11. Also try to check whether there is any error message when it do not redirect from URL1 to URL2?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I think you are misunderstanding my question. Redirect is happening even for IE11 but OnBeforeNavigate2 event is not triggered for URL2. Also, there is no difference in settings for the two browsers.

Comment: @BhavyaSharma were you able to resolve this issue?